# Django CustomUser model stores password as plain text

Tags: django, django-models

I'm developing django based website.
I'm extends auth.user model like below

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = None
    last_name = None

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_granted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = '사용자'
        verbose_name_plural = '사용자'
```

But I'm in trouble when I create new user data in django site admin.
When I create new user, the password doesn't encrypt.
I don't want to store password in plain text but hash doesn't work.

How should I handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following. But keep in mind in my example I am using email as unique field instead of username.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=150)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'users'
        verbose_name = '사용자'
        verbose_name_plural = '사용자'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.email}'
```

UserManager

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)  #---> This is the function which hashes the password.
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Comment: did this help you solve the issue?